# For the intervals $ A < x < B$ and $C < y < D$, what inequality can we form for the product xy?

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, inequality, real-numbers

If we know an interval of values for both real numbers, what can we say about the product?
If it is just $AC < xy < BD$ prove why.

Comment: Suppose $A$ and $C$ are large and negative - what then? Or $x$ and $y$ both negative, but one of $B$ and $D$ positive, and the other negative?

Comment: If $A,C$ are positive, you can say that $AC<xy<BD$. Otherwise, it's case-dependent

Comment: Watch out for assuming positive.  if $-3< -2< -1$ and $-10<-9 < -8$ then $30 < 18 < 8$ is not true.

Answer (score 1):

The key to what you can say is that you have $$x-A\gt 0; B-x\gt 0; y-C\gt 0; D-y\gt 0$$and you can safely multiply two positive numbers to get another positive number.

Answer (score 1):

Consider $-1 < 0 < 1$ and $-2 < 0 < 2$ so we figure $(-1)(-2) < 0*0 < 1*2$ and so $2 < 0 < 2$ which is clearly wrong.

We must avoid "negative flipping".

Now if $A,B,C,D$ are all positive then $A < x$ and $C < y$ so $xy > Ay > AC$ and if we do the same thing for $x < B$ and $y < D$ then $xy  < By < BD$.  And so $AC < xy < BD$.

But what if we don't know which are positive or negative?

Well we have $A < x< B$ and $C < y< D$ so $0 < x - A < B-A$ and $0 < y - C < D-C$ and we can use the above *now*

$0 < (x-A)(y-C) < (B-A)(D-C)$ so $0 < xy - Ay- Cx + AC < BD-AD-BC+AC$ so

So $Ay + Cx - AC < xy < BD-AD-BC+Ay+Cy$